# Regexp to exclude 101 and 110

Tags: regex, grammar

What is a regexp that accepts everything over the language {0,1} but has no substring 110 or 101?

Accept:

- 111111
- 000011111
- 100001000001001
- 010
- 1

Reject:

- 100110
- 010100
- 123

*Edit:* Per comments on answers below, this question is asking for a formal regular expression.

Comment: So you're only talking about numbers consisting of only one number?

Comment: @greg that doesn't have the substring 110 or 101 so it's valid.

Comment: Thought so... so @Franz's assumption is incorrect

Comment: Thinking about it again, I was not completely wrong. But I was trying to do whitelisting (and didn't go all the way), so Greg's answer IS correct and much easier also.

Comment: Actually, I take it back, since Greg's idea would even match strings. I'll fixe mine, brb.

Comment: Seems like CAdaker has got it.

Comment: No,it seems like Yaakov Belch has got it (assuming look-arounds cannot be used).

Comment: @Absolute0, you said in a comment below that you're "talking about the formal regular expressions", but in another comment you wrote "why not just do /(^([01]))*/ ?", which is hardly a formal regex.  What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limited to formal regular expression notation:

```
((1|0*|0*1)(000*))*0*(10*|1*)
```

Comment: Can this be simplified?
It seems a bit to obfuscated.

Comment: I would think so, but my brain got awfully twisted just coming up with this.  It's been too long since I studied DFAs and formal regular expressions.

Answer (score 11):

This is the solution (even without lookahead):

```
/^0*(11*$|10$|100+)*$/
```

- Start off with any number of zeros.
- Loop (know: the string parsed so far does not end with "1" or "10")

  - "1$" is ok (&stop)
  - If you find "11", then you can't read any thing except ones until you reach the end
  - "10$" is ok.
  - If you read "10" and want to go on, read one or more zeros. Then go back to the loop.

Comment: I did not test it, but it looks like you nailed it: well done! +1

Comment: $ is a look-ahead, and is not part of a formal regular expression.

Comment: @Jeremy: $ is the "end of string" condition.  you can call it \z if you want.

Comment: I think a zero-width assertion is technically a look-ahead, but whatever you want to call it, it's not part of a formal mathematical regular expression.

Answer (score 6):

You'd be best off checking if it *doesn't* match `/101|110/`

Comment: I don't think it's that simple.
not matching those 3 characters enforces a string of at least 3.
My requirement is any string, including the empty string.

Comment: That won't enforce a string length - you just need to do something like (php) if (!preg_match('/101|110/', $str)) {}

Comment: Who said we're using php? :)
I am talking about the formal regular expressions, not fancy magic ones.

Comment: @Absolute0, if this is an academic exercise, you should have said so in your original question. This is a programming Q&A site so it is not strange that Greg thought you were using some regex library from a programming language.

Comment: See my comment to the question, though. This answer is wrong, sorry. It would even match strings.

Comment: This would work *if used in conjunction* with a positive check for `\A[01]*\z`. But it's simpler to do it in a single expression with a negative lookahead.

Comment: so, /^[01]*$/ && !/101|110/ ?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work, assuming that your regex engine supports lookahead.

```
/^(1(?!01|10)|0)*$/
```

Comment: If Absolute0's question is an academic one, look-arounds are out of the question, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
/^([01])\1*$/
```

Comment: It basically checks for there being a zero or one at the beginning of the string, and then multiple (or no) occurrences of that same number after the first digit.

Comment: That would reject `1001001` which does not contain either `101` or `110` so should be accepted.

Comment: Why are you escaping the "1" in "\1"

Comment: @Absolute0, Franz is back referencing what is matched in group 1.

Comment: I'm not escaping it. It's a backreference and thus checking for the same string that was found inside the first pair of parenthesis.

And sorry. Looks like I didn't read everything...

Comment: why not just do /(^([01]))*/ ?

Answer (score -1):

The corresponding DFA is easy to draw.

There is no corresponding regex of finite size when being limited by the accepted "formal" regex syntax (lack of trivial operators like "and", "xor", "not" which are necessary in a complete algebra)

But there are many solutions , like this one

(0|100|(1|10|11*)$)*

It can be solved with possessive matching too.  (111+$) is 111++